# A limit calculation

Tags: limits-and-convergence

I wonder if the limit below $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^{-x}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{j+a}}{\Gamma(j+a+1)}$$
equals 1, for real constant $a>0$, and how shall we get this result?

Comment: Could you cite any reference where you got this limit ? And am not sure if this gives 1 because if $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{j+a}}{\Gamma(j+a+1)}$ convergent to any finit number this yield to your limit to be 0 , You have one chance if this sum diverge

Comment: @zeraouliarafik the sum should be convergent to a function related to x. You may see that each term of this series is positive and goes to ∞ while x→∞. So the limit is possible to have a non-zero result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take $$\chi(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{j+a}}{\Gamma(j+a+1)}$$ then we get, $$\chi'(x)-\chi(x)=\frac{x^{a-1}}{\Gamma(a)}$$

Hence, the solution gives $$\psi(x)=\chi(x)e^{-x}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}{\int e^{-x} x^{a-1} dx}+c$$

This means $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \psi(x) -\psi(0)=1$$

As, $$\color{grey}{{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{a-1} dx=\Gamma(a)}}$$

and $$\color{cadetblue}{\psi(0)=0} $$

So, $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \psi(x)=e^{-x}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{j+a}}{\Gamma(j+a+1)} =1$$

Comment: Alternatively: $\chi(x) = e^x \bigl(1 - \Gamma(a, x)/\Gamma(a))$ where $\Gamma(a,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-t} \mathrm{d} t$ is the incomplete $\Gamma$ function. So the limit is $1 - \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Gamma(a,x)/\Gamma(a)$ which is clearly $1$.